# Installing Software via SSHJ results in exit code 127

Tags: java, ssh, sshj

I am trying to write a software to automatically install Linpack on a CentOS Server.

[Here's the code I've been working with so far](https://pastebin.com/BHnSmhz8)

First, I upload 2 zip files to the SFTP Server that's running on CentOS, which works fine.
Then I extract those 2 files using the commands `tar xfv l_mklb_p_2020.2.001.tgz` and `tar xfv l_mpi_2019.8.254.tgz` which also work as intended.
Then I try to `cd l_mpi_2019.8.254` into the extracted folder to execute `./install.sh`

However, this is where my program fails. I get the exit code 127, which would imply that the command does not exist/can't be found

Executing these commands in the same order manually over PuTTy works just fine though, so I am unsure why it isn't working in my program. Maybe the `/` gets escaped so the command that's executed is `.//install.sh`? How would I check for that though? Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Is the executable flag for `./install.sh` set? You can set it using `chmod` or call the script with a shell e.g. `bash ./install.sh`.

Comment: @LinFelix thanks for the suggestions!
I tried replacing `./install.sh` with `bash ./install.sh` but that also returned 127 as exit code.
I then tried adding the command `chmod +x install.sh` (before executing the script) which returned a 1.